# Dynamic Time Warping to find distance in stochastic way

Tags: time-series, classification, pattern-recognition, sequential-pattern-mining

Is there a formulation of DTW that allows to deal with uncertainty or to utilize knowledge of the probabilistic structure of the signal? I would like to have a formulation similar to HMM but stay in DTW paradigm.

Why do I need that? I have several examples of a time series pattern that I want to find in the data. The amount of examples is not enough to build a complex model (e.g. HMM). On the other hand, I would like to leverage all the examples given at once and not use these examples one after another. I am wondering if there is DTW formulation that allows to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "leverage all the examples given at once", then you can optimally average all the patterns [a] into a single template and use that.

However, you should not do that if the patterns are polymorphic.

A good resource for DTW is [b]

[a] http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/ICDM_2014_DTW_average.pdf
[b] http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

Comment: Yes, I would like  "leverage all the examples given at once" but averaging might be too risky, since yes, template are similar but sometimes might have high variation. So, I am searching for a method that would provide me some uncertainty on every points when performring DTW.